# Argument of type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'

Tags: typescript

My code:

```
const configPath = process.env[`${configPrefix}_CONFIG_PATH`]
    ? path.resolve(process.env[`${configPrefix}_CONFIG_PATH`])
    : path.resolve('ab', 'config');
```

The error:

```
application/libs/config.ts:18:20 - error TS2345: Argument of type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.
  Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.

18     ? path.resolve(process.env[`${configPrefix}_CONFIG_PATH`])
```

Why is this complaining? I'm doing a check on `` process.env[`${configPrefix}_CONFIG_PATH`] `` to see if it is undefined then deciding with `?` and `:` which value to take.

Answer (score 0):

I got around the issue with the following code:

```
const configPath = process.env[`${configPrefix}_CONFIG_PATH`] || path.resolve('ab', 'config');
```

Doesn't answer though why Typescript doesn't work in my first examples.

Answer (score 0):

In your first example, if `process.env["${configPrefix}_CONFIG_PATH"]` exists, you return `path.resolve(process.env["${configPrefix}_CONFIG_PATH"])`, but wrapping it in `path.resolve()` may apparently still result in `undefined`.

```
const configPath = process.env[`${configPrefix}_CONFIG_PATH`]
    ? path.resolve(process.env[`${configPrefix}_CONFIG_PATH`])
    : path.resolve('ab', 'config');
```

In your own answer, you return the same value that you checked for undefined so in that case you don't have the problem.

Comment: Hmm not quite according to `path.resolve()`s description: `Starting from leftmost {from} parameter, resolves {to} to an absolute path.

If {to} isn't already absolute, {from} arguments are prepended in right to left order, until an absolute path is found. If after using all {from} paths still no absolute path is found, the current working directory is used as well. The resulting path is normalized, and trailing slashes are removed unless the path gets resolved to the root directory.`? Something I'm missing?

Comment: This is in the docs, but you have to check the Typescript definition for `path.resolve()`, because the Typescript compiler apparently thinks it may return undefined. You should be able to right-click on `path.resolve` and then `go to definition`. Or you can check the types here, but that's a bit of a maze: https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/types/webpack

Comment: In any case, if you return the same thing that you checked for not being undefined, you have a safe solution